# Eclipse:enable right to left in a view

Tags: eclipse, right-to-left

Is it possible to show a view (e.g. Tasks) in right to left direction?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
In Tasks view under View Menu option Configure Columns. Will allow you to change the order of the columns so that you can display it to look like Right to left.
**To find View Menu see below image.**
[image]

Comment: I could not find View Menu in Tasks

Comment: added image for menu position

Comment: Thank you for the image. However, how changing the order of columns is going to change texts inside of columns to look like Right to Left?

Comment: Sorry this change the only order of columns from Left to Rigth but not text.